# Two blocks accelerating at different rates in an accelerating pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Two masses are connected by a string which passes over a pulley accelerating upward at a rate as shown. If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the accelerations of bodies 1 and 2 respectively, find the value of $A$ (in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$).

[image: Figure]

**My attempt:**

For the body 1:-
$$T-m_1g-m_1A=m_1a_1$$

For the body 2:-
$$T-m_2g-m_2A=-m_2a_2$$

Subtracting the two equations we get:-
$$m_1g-m_2g+m_1A-m_2A=m_1a_1+m_2a_2$$

$$(m_1-m_2)A=m_1a_1+m_2a_2+m_2g-m_1g$$

I am not sure about this but assuming the numbers on the blocks are in fact the masses we can substitute $m_1=1kg$ and $m_2=2kg$. But even then there is still the $g$ variable I am not able to eliminate and by adding the initial equations a new tension $T$ variable shows up, what should I do?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question asks you to eliminate $g$, however you can apply conservation of string to further reduce the equation,
$a_1=-a_2$

Answer (score 0):

Considering effective gravity as it is an accelerating system,
$$
g_{eff}=g+A
$$
Now,
$$
T-m_1(g+A)=m_1a_1\\
m_2(g+A)-T=m_2a_2
$$
Applying string constraint,
$$
|T|.|a_1|-|T|.|a_2|=0
\\
|a_1|=|a_2|
$$
Now you have got enough equations to finish of the problem!